# The Composer installer script did not run correctly [exit code 259] and no output was returned

Tags: composer-php, laravel-9

Hey guys i just got a new device so i tried installing composer on it, so i downloaded it from getcomposer.org
and i tried installing but then after clicking next on the ready to install page, it took me to the page where the installation progress shows but it ended up with the error message below:

"An error occcured. Clicking retry may resolve this issue.
The Composer installer script did not run correctly [exit code 259] and no output was returned."

Answer (score 0):

Please deactivate your antivirus and run composer again it should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues with SMADAV Anti-Virus. which blocks the scripts from running. just Deactivate the antivirus and retry; it will work.