# Composer install failed. The Composer installer script did not run correctly [exit code 259]

Tags: windows, installation, composer-php

The Composer installer script did not run correctly [exit code 259] and no output was returned.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfODw.png)

I tried hard to install composer from install via cmd and even the GUI now. I have uninstalled my xampp many times to install composer and even I have also installed xampp version 5 but the result is still the same or the error remains, I have also turned off the antivirus and various others. Please help me

Comment: What do you mean by "Composer installer script"? Can you share more details about that, and how this problem relates to [tag:user-interface] and [tag:google-cloud-composer] and [tag:visual-composer]? These tags target completely unrelated techniques

Comment: Please use the search before posting your question. Please provide textual information, not images. [help] [QA reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72241343/367456)

Answer (score 0):

This error message means that the Composer installer script has encountered an error and has stopped running. The exit code 259 indicates that there was a problem with the script and it could not be completed.

To resolve this issue, follow these steps:

1. Check for any error messages in the terminal or log files.
2. Ensure that all dependencies and requirements for the composer install are met.
3. Check if the environment variables are set correctly.
4. Try running the command with elevated privileges, i.e. using sudo.
5. If the error persists, try uninstalling and reinstalling Composer.
6. If the problem persists, you can also seek assistance from the Composer community or reach out to the vendor for support.

Comment: hi sir thanks for respond. can you tell me in detail and screenshots or similar video tutorials, please